# Travelling to using two passports where one is not ok with dual citizenship

Tags: dual-nationality

I have two passports where one of them is not OK with with dual citizenship. As suggested by previous questions posed that I should fly to a neutral country - "C" which does not need visa as transit and then fly into the single citizenship country -"B" -entering using B passport.

However on my return to A (dual citizenship) country via the neutral country using my A  passport, would it not be strange not to have an B country exit stamp on the A passport especially you just flew out from B country? (As you enter and leave your (single citizenship) B country using its own passport)
Would the neutral country's immigration question this and report to your  B country?

Comment: You should be flying out of B back to C before you return to A - otherwise you'll need to present some evidence of a visa for A in your B passport before the airline will let you board. But in any case - A doesn't care because they don't have a problem with dual citizenship. As long as you're not breaking any of A's rules, A isn't going to scan your passport for matching entry/exit stamps, nor are they going to bother with getting involved with B's issues.

Comment: If A *does* look at your travel history, you can just show them the other passport -- they're the ones who don't care about dual citizenship.  But even for countries that *do* restrict multiple citizenship: how would they know you'd been to B?  You book the A-C and C-B flights on separate tickets.  To anyone looking at your trip between A and C, it simply looks like a trip between A and C.

Comment: In general, a country is not "OK" or "not OK" with dual nationality. You are either a national of a country, according to its law, or you're not. Are you trying to hide the fact that you have already automatically lost one country's nationality and are still pretending to be its national?

Comment: This is way too vague. You need to tell us which countries you are talking about so somebody with specific knowledge of the laws and policies of that country can weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

In general you it's highly advisable to enter and leave a country on the same passport. Switching passports can be a bit of a chore depending on the actual entry and exit procedures and how much information the airlines (if you are flying) need to collect and transmit to the authorities.

I recently flew on a multi-country trip and switched passports on the leg from Germany to South Korea, i.e. I left Germany on one passport and entered South Korea on a different one. Lufthansa actually needed to know about this and collected the information accordingly. However, they were apparently used to doing this, so in this case, it was no problem.